# Programming: Detect the direction and stop of change of a number

Tags: functional-programming

Any language, just pseudocode.

I'm searching around for an algorithm that detects direction and the stop of changes to a number. E.g.:

```
function detectChange(int number) {
  if number is rising return "rising"
  if number is dropping return "dropping"
  if number is unchanged return "unchanged"
}

main() {
  int number

  while(true) {
    //The read doesn't always happen
    if readObscure.readoccured() {
      //read the number from an obscure source
      number = readObscure()
      print(detectChange(number))
    }
  }
}
```

I've been working on an approach with a time delta but with little success. One problem is e.g. that with the timing approach I always miss the last change. Maybe I could solve that too but it's already pretty hacky. 
**So I'd be glad about a clean "textbook" solution, preferably without using time but just logic**. If there's none without time, but still a clean solution, I'd appreciate that too.

Solution can be written in any "human readable" language (no haskell please) or pseudocode, I don't care.

I should have mentioned that the readObscure() function may also return the same number over and over again, or won't return a number at all, in which case I want to assume that the number is "unchanged".

Let's also update this with some examples:

readObscure() returns the numbers 1,2,14,15,**8**,17,20
This should be "rising"

readObscure() returns the numbers 1,2,14,15,17,20,20,20
This should be "rising" and then "unchanged"

So the question also is, how to define rising, unchanged, dropping. I'd like someone who maybe worked on those problems before to define it. The result should equal a "human sorting", so I look at the numbers and can immediatly tell, they are not rising, or they are rising.

I've been made aware of [**Rx** (Reactive Extensions)](https://rx.codeplex.com/) 
But for my personal case this is using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut.

Comment: It seems like it's impossible to do without measuring a time delta, but I've seen lots of things done with pure timeless logic I could'nt have thought of myself, that's why I formulated the question like this.

Comment: I don't see where time enters the scene at all - the only thing that seems to be missing is a place where you can remember the last seen number - so if you want a *pure* approach you can just pass this around like `function detectChange(int number, int lastNumber) ..` btw: you ask for *readable* code and present *javascript*? ... uhmmm

Comment: :) I know the problem seems that simple. But think about it again, I want to give an "analysis" of what's happening to the number right now, it's not as easy as "a > b". I should have mentioned that the readObscure() function may also return the same number over and over again, or won't return a number at all, in which case I want to assume that the number is "unchanged".

Comment: it's still only "a > b" - if your function does not return a number make it explicite and just use the old one again ...

Comment: maybe you should have a look at Rx ;)

Comment: I updated my question to formulate the problem more specific.

Comment: your first example is very suspect - why is this not `rising, dropping, rising`? - Overall your question is very unclear can you give a few more "input -> output" pairs? The ones I see seem to contradict themselves (do you want one or more outputs for example)

Comment: Rx seems to be the thing I want - sadly I don't have .net to solve this. It also doesn't have to be overly sophisticated.

Comment: there are versions of Rx for *lots* of languages ([including javascript](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS))

Answer (score 2):

Just make it so that whenever you add a value:

- Take the value of the current and the last value, compute its delta.
- Then, add it to wherever you're holding the deltas.

If you want something to "fire" everytime you "add a value," it's probably best to bind it to the container or some sort of callback/event-based mechanism/structure to ensure this. Boost.Signals2 (C++) is supposed to be a good way to handle this, but something as simple as creating an asynchronous thread of execution to compute and then push your value to the back of the storage vector would be good enough.

Comment: I've been thinking about taking multiple samples, however I'd need to find a way to work with a variable amount of samples. Still I don't get around the time delta. Numbers can be equal for 100 milliseconds but in fact still be rising.

Comment: @bortran Then just take the sum of multiple deltas. Shouldn't be too hard.